# Disqus moderation page not working in WordPress admin section

Tags: comments, disqus

If I login to my Admin section and click Comments on the left, the Disqus moderation page does not load. On further inspection this is because it's trying to load the page over http:// and my blog is loaded via https:// so it is being stopped. Everything else loads via https:// but I don't know how/where to change this page to do so. Link to [my site](https://scotthelme.co.uk/) if you need it.

Comment: What is "disqus moderation page"? :) Have you tried contacting its developers about the issue?

Comment: When logged in to the WP admin if you click Comments on the left it's the replacement page that Disqus provides to replace the standard one. Yes I've contacted them but no response yet, thought I'd ask here to see if anyone else has had the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a response from Disqus Support regarding this issue:

> Hi Scott,
>
> To clarify, the Disqus moderation panel in Wordpress is not intended
>   to be used with https. If you would like to use the moderation panel
>   in https you’ll need to go to the Disqus moderation panel directly at:
>   https://scotthelme.disqus.com/admin/moderate/#/approved
>
> If you have any trouble or other questions, please let us know.
>
> Qarly
>
> Disqus Product Support